# Spark sql and hive causing "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, hive

I am new to big data. I have developed an spark application using Scala to communicate with hive. It is working fine on Intellij idea. But when I am building an jar file with all dependency I am getting the error

> Error: Could not find or load main class

After further debugging I have found that when I am including spark SQL or hive then I am getting the error. It is a maven project. Please have a look on my pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>spk</groupId>
<artifactId>spk</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.101tec/zkclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
        <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
        <version>0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <!--<arg>-make:transitive</arg>-->
                            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                            <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <useFile>false</useFile>
                <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
                <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
                <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                    <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the command you are using to run your jar?

Comment: java -jar jarfile.jar. Building excluding spark SQL is working fine

Comment: Use spark-submit to run your jar. Follow the link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: I have tried the spark-submit also but same error

Comment: I have the same error! in the build.gradle file, if I include `compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.0.1'`, the jar does not work. If excluding this statement, it works. Any update from your side, @BinodSarkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I have got the answer. There are some problem with Intellij Idea build with all dependency. 
I have done the following steps:

> 1) Added to the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>spk.kspark</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

> 2) Go to the project directory and open Ubuntu terminal
>
> 3) mvn install
>
> 4) mvn clean compile assembly:single or mvn package assembly:single